# Is there a way to avoid typing whole package names in the Scala interpreter in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala

I am currently writing a project in Scala in Eclipse and it's a real hassle having to type whole package names to get to the classes I've written. For example:

If I write a class Sender in package com.ab.cd.ef.gh then whenever I try and use that object I have to do something like:

```
val sender = com.ab.cd.ef.gh.Sender.getSender
```

or something similar. Is there a way to set the interpreter so that I only have to type in

```
val sender = Sender.getSender
```

?

Comment: is `import com.ab.cd.ef.gh._` not working for you?

Comment: Haha, it does. I only tried import com.ab.cd.ef.gh and that didn't work. Thank you. Is there a way to mark this as answered?

Comment: I've put it as an answer now.

Comment: If you import `com.ab.cd.ef.gh`, then you can refer to `Sender` as `gh.Sender`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `import com.ab.cd.ef.gh._` to import the whole package. See [here](http://jcranky.com/2009/08/18/import-statements-in-scala/) for more details on scala import statements

Answer (score 6):

As already answered you can use `import` to import stuff in the repl.

To avoid importing the same stuff on each restart you can put your common imports and definitions in a file, say `imports.scala` and preload that file in the repl with the `-i` switch.

```
✗ cat imports.scala 
import collection.mutable.HashSet

✗ scala -i imports.scala 
Loading imports.scala...
import collection.mutable.HashSet

Welcome to Scala version 2.9.0.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_26).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> HashSet(1, 2)
res0: scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[Int] = Set(2, 1)
```